# How to get the coordinates of an image within a region in sikuli?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am just evaluating sikuli for one of our automation testing. I am trying to execute a script that can find the location of an image in a region.

This is the .sikuli script that I have written.

```
match = find("regionImage.png")  # The actual image here.
z = match.findAll("requiredImage.png")
for icon in z:
    print icon.getTarget()
    click(icon)
    time.sleep(3)

 #Output
 L(693,464)@S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]
 L(693,519)@S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]
```

The problem that I am having is getTarget gives the coordinates corresponding to the whole screen. What would be perfect is to get the location with respect to a set region. Is it possible? ( Ofcourse you can always subtract but just was wondering if there are any more good way )

Answer (score 1):

the `getTarget()` method that you are using returns an object of class `Location` that in this case points to a center of **current** `Match` object. This match is not aware of the `Region` it was located in.

The only way to achieve your goal will be manual calculation. It should't be a complex task as Sikuli exposes a decent API in regards to patterns locations. Have a look at the documentation [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#creating-a-region-setting-and-getting-attributes) to get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for `.getX()` and `.getY()`.